# List of any `DataKind` in GADT

Tags: haskell, gadt, data-kinds

### Disclaimer

GADTs & DataKinds are unexplored territory for me, so some of the limitations and capabilities of them are unknown to me.

## The Question

So I'm writing an AST for a JavaScript code emitter, and I've identified one edge case between expressions and that is that they can either be a reference or not. So I've used GADTS and datakinds to type this aspect of JavaScript expression semantics. The ast looks something like this.

### Subset of the expression AST

```
-- at the moment I'm just using a bool to identify if the expression 
-- behaves as an reference, but I'll probably change it due to the fact
-- a bool is pretty vague

data JSExp :: Bool -> * where

  JSNumber :: Double -> JSExp False
  JSBool :: Bool -> JSExp False

  JSReference :: Text -> JSExp True
  JSProperty :: JSExp a -> Text -> JSExp True
  JSAssign :: JSExp True -> JSExp b -> JSExp b
```

This looks all fine and dandy, because an assignment expression requires the first expression to be a reference like a property expression (`"test".shadyProperty`) or a reference/identifier.

### The problem

Now I want to add an array literal expression, in JavaScript it shouldn't matter what is in this list so lists like this are legal

```
[a, 1, true, a.b]
```

In my AST however this is not legal because there are multiple types in the list

```
data JSExp :: Bool -> * where

  -- ...

  JSArray :: [JSExp ???] -> JSExp False

let aref = JSReference "a"
in  JSArray [aref, JSNumber 2, JSBool True, JSProp aref "b"]
```

What goes in the place of `???` for the type? A similar problem occurs when I want to build out a constructor for JSObject's and JSFunctionCall's, as these are also expressions.

### Idris's soultion

In Idris `???` would look something like this.

```
data JSExp : Bool -> Type where

  JSArray : List (JSExp _) -> JSExp False
  JSNumber : Float -> JSExp False
  JSBool : Bool -> JSExp False

  -- ...
```

### Potenial soultions

#### Wrapping type

One soultion that isn't like the Idris one, would to have a wrapper type like this

```
data JSExpWrap = Refs (JSExp True) | NoRef (JSExp False)
```

This would make the api of my library gross and it's not what I'm looking for.

## In Summary

I'm looking for the equivalent that's found in Idris, and an explanation of the implications of the solution. If there's no equivalent, a solution of the next best thing is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use existentials:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, PolyKinds #-}

data Exists :: (k -> *) -> * where
  This :: p x -> Exists p

data JSExp :: Bool -> * where
  ...
  JSArray :: [Exists JSExp] -> JSExp False

test = let aref = JSReference "a"
       in  JSArray [This aref, This (JSNumber 2), This (JSBool True), This (JSProperty aref "b")]
```

Or with some sugar:

```
infixr 5 !:
(!:) :: p x -> [Exists p] -> [Exists p]
x !: xs = This x : xs

test = let aref = JSReference "a"
       in  JSArray $ aref !: JSNumber 2 !: JSBool True !: JSProperty aref "b" !: []
```

Comment: I guess this is a bit better than a multiple constructors for a wrapper types. On a side note would you be able to explain how the PolyKinds extension work or link to a good explanation, I've been figure that out as well.

Comment: @ABot, the `PolyKinds` extension just allows you to treat certain types as kinds. You can read [the original paper](http://dreixel.net/research/pdf/ghp.pdf) for details.

Comment: Thanks by the way, but unfortunately it's not exactly what I'm looking for (mentioned at the bottom of my question), but it's somewhat nicer than what I was thinking, if no one posts an answer with exactly what I'm after in the next few days, I'll mark this as the answer to my problem.

Comment: @ABot, I don't think there is a better solution. Even in Agda you would use dependent pairs, which represent the same existential quantification. It would be a bit nicer with coercive subtyping, but that's far away from Haskell. Have you really tried your solution in Idris? If it works, it's a mystery for me. BTW, I updated the answer a bit.

Comment: Well the compiler didn't complain about the type definition, however I never used the type. I just tried it just then, and it turns out `_` is just an anonymous type parameter. Looks like you're right.