# The limit set of types with new data like `Tree a`

Tags: haskell, type-systems, gadt, data-kinds, phantom-types

Exploring and studing type system in Haskell I've found some problems.

1) Let's consider polymorphic type as Binary Tree:

```
 data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show
```

And, for example, I want to limit my considerations only with `Tree Int`, `Tree Bool` and `Tree Char`. Of course, I can make a such new type:

```
data TreeIWant = T1 (Tree Int) | T2 (Tree Bool) | T3 (Tree Char) deriving Show
```

But could it possible to make new restricted type (for homogeneous trees) in more elegant (and without new tags like `T1`,`T2`,`T3`) way (perhaps with some advanced type extensions)?

2) Second question is about trees with heterogeneous values. I can do them with usual Haskell, i.e. I can do the new helping type, contained tagged heterogeneous values:

```
data HeteroValues = H1 Int | H2 Bool | H3 Char deriving Show
```

and then make tree with values of this type:

```
type TreeH = Tree HeteroValues
```

But could it possible to make new type (for heterogeneous trees) in more elegant (and without new tags like `H1`,`H2`,`H3`) way (perhaps with some advanced type extensions)?
I know about [heterogeneous list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438040/haskell-heterogeneous-list-for-data-with-phantom-variable), perhaps it is the same question?

Comment: The answer about *hetrogenous lists* can be applied to trees (without much) modification, except for using `fmap` over `map`, etc. The principle is demonstrated on a list, but you can use it on all sorts of "functor-like" things.

Comment: There are several ways to do roughly what you asked for. I wouldn't say any of them is really better than the explicitly-tagged alternative-type, but perhaps if you explain the application you need this for we can give some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question #2, it's easy to construct a "restricted" heterogeneous type without explicit tags using a GADT and a type class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Thing where
  T :: THING a => a -> Thing
class THING a
```

Now, declare `THING` instances for the the things you want to allow:

```
instance THING Int
instance THING Bool
instance THING Char
```

and you can create `Things` and lists (or trees) of `Things`:

```
> t1 = T 'a'       -- Char is okay
> t2 = T "hello"   -- but String is not
... type error ...
> tl = [T (42 :: Int), T True, T 'x']
> tt = Branch (Leaf (T 'x')) (Leaf (T False))
>
```

In terms of the type names in your question, you have:

```
type HeteroValues = Thing
type TreeH = Tree Thing
```

You can use the same type class with a new GADT for question #1:

```
data ThingTree where
  TT :: THING a => Tree a -> ThingTree
```

and you have:

```
type TreeIWant = ThingTree
```

and you can do:

```
> tt1 = TT $ Branch (Leaf 'x') (Leaf 'y')
> tt2 = TT $ Branch (Leaf 'x') (Leaf False)
... type error ...
>
```

That's all well and good, until you try to **use** any of the values you've constructed.  For example, if you wanted to write a function to extract a `Bool` from a possibly boolish `Thing`:

```
maybeBool :: Thing -> Maybe Bool
maybeBool (T x) = ...
```

you'd find yourself stuck here.  Without a "tag" of some kind, there's no way of determining if `x` is a `Bool`, `Int`, or `Char`.

Actually, though, you *do* have an implicit tag available, namely the `THING` type class dictionary for `x`.  So, you can write:

```
maybeBool :: Thing -> Maybe Bool
maybeBool (T x) = maybeBool' x
```

and then implement `maybeBool'` in your type class:

```
class THING a where
  maybeBool' :: a -> Maybe Bool
instance THING Int where
  maybeBool' _ = Nothing
instance THING Bool where
  maybeBool' = Just
instance THING Char where
  maybeBool' _ = Nothing
```

and you're golden!

Of course, if you'd used explicit tags:

```
data Thing = T_Int Int | T_Bool Bool | T_Char Char
```

then you could skip the type class and write:

```
maybeBool :: Thing -> Maybe Bool
maybeBool (T_Bool x) = Just x
maybeBool _ = Nothing
```

In the end, it turns out that the best Haskell representation of an algebraic sum of three types is just an algebraic sum of three types:

```
data Thing = T_Int Int | T_Bool Bool | T_Char Char
```

Trying to avoid the need for explicit tags will probably lead to a lot of inelegant boilerplate elsewhere.

*Update:* As @DanielWagner pointed out in a comment, you can use `Data.Typeable` in place of this boilerplate (effectively, have GHC generate a lot of boilerplate for you), so you can write:

```
import Data.Typeable

data Thing where
  T :: THING a => a -> Thing
class Typeable a => THING a

instance THING Int
instance THING Bool
instance THING Char

maybeBool :: Thing -> Maybe Bool
maybeBool = cast
```

This perhaps seems "elegant" at first, but if you try this approach in real code, I think you'll regret losing the ability to pattern match on `Thing` constructors at usage sites (and so having to substitute chains of `cast`s and/or comparisons of `TypeRep`s).

Comment: If you `class Typeable a => THING a`, then you don't need to go back and add one casting method per instance to the class.

Comment: True.  I added a note at the end.